# Msgpack Generic serialization/desrialization

Tags: java, generics, serialization, deserialization, msgpack

I am using msgpack integrated with Axon framework. So on the axon event handler i get object's on runtime which can be of any type.As the object type is unknown, i want to use generic serialization/deserialiation. The serialization is done properly but the issue arises when i deserialize the byte Stream.
ex:

```
public <S, T> T deserialize(SerializedObject<S> serializedObject) {
    byte[] serializedBytes= (byte[]) serializedObject.getData();
    Object bytes = null;
    try {
        bytes=objectMapper.readValue(serializedBytes,Object.class);
        System.out.println("After deserialization : "+bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return (T) bytes;
}
```

where serializedObject has custom method getData() which contains the serialized bytes.
Here i read the value & give representation as `Object.class` I always get a `LinkedHashMap` in return value for target.
Is there any standard way to perform **GENERIC serialization / deserialization** for any object type using msgpack.

Answer (score 0):

Without type information it won't be possible to deserialize the object at runtime using msgpack [see here](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-java/issues/228)